# what is the process of building libsmbclient.4.18.4 without using samba suite?

Tags: makefile, samba, libsmbclient

I configured the samba.4.18 on my system now I want to build smbclient packages in seperate machine.
But getting lot of dependencies.

How can I figure out what are the dependencies needed to build smbclient independently and how to resolve those dependencies